# Titletoc and minitoc are not working with cftsectionname (memoir class document)

Tags: memoir, titletoc, minitoc

In my `memoir` class document I would like to get a minitable of content after each `\part` 's title. I have tried the `minitoc` package, but it is not working with the `titlesec` package used in my document. Besides, the `titletoc` package is bugging with my memoir class document.

Indeed this code is not working :

```
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionname}{Section } %Section doesn't appear 
\cftsetindents{section}{1.4em}{4mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\itshape\bfseries}
```

If `\usepackage{titletoc`} is enabled, the word "Section" will not appear in my toc.

What can I do ?

```
    \documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}  
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionname}{Section }
        \cftsetindents{section}{1.4em}{4mm}
        \renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\itshape\bfseries} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\part{Part ONE}
\startcontents[parts]
\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART ONE}
\section{Something is wrong with section}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART ONE}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is as a result of a conflict between [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc). `memoir` provides a [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)-style adjustment, while `titletoc` uses something completely different.

Comment: SO, what can I do ?

Comment: `titlesec/titletoc` and `minitoc` are completely incompatible to each other, as well as `memoir` and `minitoc` should be used only with caution (all is stated in the `minitoc` manual)